# How do I find maximum value in a multi dimensional array

Tags: java

I have a multi dimensional array with the rows containing String values and the columns contains integer values. I want to find the maximum value in this case maximum score which is in the columns

Here is my code so far(JAVA)

```
public class HighScore {
    int row;
    int col;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void maxscore() {
        System.out.println("How many students are you entering scores for");
        int st_num = input.nextInt();
        String[][] arr = new String[st_num][1];
        for (row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the student's name");
            String name = input.next();
            for (col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the students's score");
                int score = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Highest score entered was");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HighScore obj = new HighScore();
        obj.maxscore();
    }
}
```

So um if u have any suggestions or answers PLEASE HELP

Comment: Let's say I ask you to tell me what the highest number is in list {5, 3, 2, 4, 1, 9}. How would you, step by step, determine this?

Comment: @KarryAlams You have to do String[st_num][2]; 2 instead of 1 because indexes start at 0 BUT when you initialize arrays you have to type the numeric value from 1 and not from zero. And then please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191408/how-to-sort-multidimensional-string-array-by-one-column-in-integer-value-in-java question. I had the same question as you have and it's answered.

Comment: You have no idea how to determine that 9 is the largest number in a list I provided you?

Comment: If you can't in plain English describe how you would find the largest number in that list of numbers, you aren't having an issue with how to code the solution, you have an issue of not knowing what the solution is first!

Comment: Ok then give me the solution

Comment: And I'm just an average Java programmer and I really don't understand the solution to your question @creativecreatorormaybenot so could you help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your code like this and I will add a method at the bottom so that you can sort it then. I will add the missin sysout too:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HighScore {

    int row;

    int col;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void maxscore() {
        System.out.println("How many students are you entering scores for");
        int st_num = input.nextInt();
        String[][] arr = new String[st_num][2]; //you need two columns for Student names AND score
        for (row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the student's name");
            arr[row][0] = input.next(); //puts the student name into the first column in every row you have

            System.out.println("Please enter the students's score");
            arr[row][1] = Integer.toString(input.nextInt()); //puts the score into the second column of the row and you need to cast the int to a string
        }
        System.out.println("All scores listed. Highest value at the top: ");

        arr = sortByScore(arr); //sorts the array with created sort method

        for(String[] s : arr) { //goes through the array after its sorted and prints it out
            System.out.println("Students name: " + s[0]);
            System.out.println("Students score: " + s[1]);
        }

        String[][] topScore = new String[1][2]; //will just have the top score

        for(int i = 0; i < topScore.length; i++) { //just goes through one time anyways and then puts the top score onto the topScore array
            topScore[i][0] = arr[0][0]; //the first value is the highest so it takes 0 index
            topScore[i][1] = arr[0][1];
        }



        System.out.println("\nHighest score: ");

        for(String[] s : topScore) { //puts out highest score
            System.out.println("Best students name: " + s[0]);
            System.out.println("Best students score: " + s[1]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HighScore obj = new HighScore();
        obj.maxscore();
    }

    private String[][] sortByScore(String[][] in) {
        String[][] out = Arrays.stream(in) //this uses java 8 streams and takes the in[][] which is in your case the array "arr"
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> -Integer.parseInt(x[1]))) //sorts it
            .toArray(String[][]::new); //puts it onto the out array

            return out; //and returns the out array back
    }
}
```

I hope that I helped you!

Example console log:

```
How many students are you entering scores for
5
Please enter the student's name
Jay
Please enter the students's score
10
Please enter the student's name
Peet
Please enter the students's score
102
Please enter the student's name
John
Please enter the students's score
52
Please enter the student's name
Zack
Please enter the students's score
1
Please enter the student's name
Fen
Please enter the students's score
95
All scores listed. Highest value at the top: 
Students name: Peet
Students score: 102
Students name: Fen
Students score: 95
Students name: John
Students score: 52
Students name: Jay
Students score: 10
Students name: Zack
Students score: 1

Highest score: 
Best students name: Peet
Best students score: 102
```

Comment: I keep getting an error message incompatible types: no instances of type variables T exist so that Stream<T> conforms to String[][] …  in the private sortByScore method

Comment: Never mind the error @creativecreatormaybenot Ive fixed that but your code still doesnt solve the problem. The program on its own should be able the arrange the scores, not relying on the user to enter the highest score first. So no it hasn't helped

Comment: Oh haha found the mistake. I changed the code! You have to do arr = sortByScore(arr); instead of just sortByScore(arr). Sorry my bad but it works now perfectly fine.